# How to add my function "new page" in my index.js with cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm pretty new in mobile app developpement and I would like to know how to simplify my code. I would like to add my script in my index.js page.

You can see my function to go to another page it's working but I don't like to have my javascript code in the same page than my html/css code.

Thank you :)

```js
(function () {
    "use strict";

    document.addEventListener( 'deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind( this ), false );

    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Gérer les événements de suspension et de reprise Cordova
        document.addEventListener( 'pause', onPause.bind( this ), false );
        document.addEventListener('resume', onResume.bind(this), false);

        document.getElementById("goPageOne").onclick = function goPageOne();
        
        // TODO: Cordova a été chargé. Effectuez l'initialisation qui nécessite Cordova ici.
        var parentElement = document.getElementById('deviceready');
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');
        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');
        
        // ajout d'une fonction vibration
        //navigator.vibrate(2000);
    };

    function onPause() {
        // TODO: cette application a été suspendue. Enregistrez l'état de l'application ici.
        
    };

    function onResume() {
        // TODO: cette application a été réactivée. Restaurez l'état de l'application ici.
        
    };

    //Function go to another page
    

});
```

```html
<button id="goPageOne">Memo</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("goPageOne").onclick = function () {
        location.href = "../www/homememo.html";
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok there is something weid with the window.open of cordova so I've just changed the function by something more simple without any function. I have replaced the function by an href like :

```html
<form action="index.html">
<button type="submit" id="b1">Quitter</button>
</form>
```